# .htaccess RewriteRule .php extension conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to put all my php files in a separate folder so this is my attempt
in `.htaccess`.

```
DirectoryIndex /PUBLIC/index.php

RewriteEngine on
#Startpage Header Banner
RewriteRule ^header_banner(.*) PUBLIC/template/start/header_banner/$1
#Public files
RewriteRule ^css(.*)\.css PUBLIC/css/$1\.css
RewriteRule ^js(.*)\.js PUBLIC/js/$1\.js
RewriteRule ^symbol(.*) PUBLIC/symbol/$1
#All PHP Requests
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /RESOURCES/$1\.php
```

Everything works fine but when it comes to the last line where I want to redirect my php request to another folder I got this error.

[image]

When I change the extension to `.html` like `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php RESOURCES/$1\.html` or in something else the code works just as normal.

[image]

Why the server throws out an exception on this?

Comment: It's ErrorCode 500. Like I pointed out in my question it works properly when I change the extension to anything else than `.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding,

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

above

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /RESOURCES/$1\.php`

can get you the job done. Since the request you're making is not an actual PHP file, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` passes the condition and process the rule.

Specifying `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /RESOURCES/$1\.php` alone makes the page redirect too many times to the same page since the request you're making has a `php` extension and the destination file has `.php` extension as well.

Comment: You mean this line of code `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /RESOURCES/$1\.php` make my server a lot of unnecessary redirects?

Comment: Yeah. Because it takes `.php` and redirects it to another `.php` file and that `.php` redirects to another `.php` and so on and it looks like you're repeating the process thus making it redirect indefinitely.

Comment: The line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` you provide works just fine. No infinite redirects. What would you suggest how to solve this?

Comment: `What would you suggest how to solve this?` What do you mean by this? Because you said the problem was resolved.

Comment: That's what I thought but you said that it wont do the job.

Comment: I mean doing `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /RESOURCES/$1\.php` alone won't get it to work. Because, in this specific case, you need to write `RewriteCond` to make it work.

Comment: oh ok I am sorry, I got the idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161407/discussion-between-perumal-and-doctype-html).